# AWS IAM Policy validation through dry-run API calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-go

I am working on a tool which takes IAM policy as JSON and creates the policy on aws. I am using aws-sdk-go for building the tool. I am looking for a way through which I can validate the policy before executing it on aws. Does AWS provide some sort of API to dry-run the policy creation or something like that?

The things I have tried:
I am validating the policy field by field.

- Effect field must be `Allow` or `Deny`
- For Action field, I added a dictionary in my tool which map service to the valid actions. Problem with this approach is it requires a lot of maintenance. AWS keep releasing new services and action and I have to update the dictionary.
- For a resource, it should be valid ARN.

A couple of other validations are added but its really tough to add all validation checks manually. I believe, aws must be providing some sort of dry-run facility for a policy.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS API exposes a policy simulator endpoint. You should will functions that make it easy to use the policy simulator at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/iam/ and specifically https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/iam/#IAM.SimulateCustomPolicy.

The policy simulator will allow you to validate the json of your policy, and verify that your intent is expressed in the outcome of the permissions you grant in the policy. You can supply context keys such as *aws:SourceIp, aws:RequestedRegion* etc.

Comment: It does not validate the json schema. For example:
`
{
"Effect":"Allow",
"Action":"invalid:invalid",
"Resource":"some valid ARN of resource"
}`
is a valid policy as per simulator API.
Custome simulator only tells what principal can perform what sort of action of what resource. 
Custom simulator helps very less when it comes to validating the `Condition` element of policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON Schema to do some validations.
If you look online you can find some sample IAM Json Schemas on github.
here is an example of one:

https://gist.github.com/jstewmon/ee5d4b7ec0d8d60cbc303cb515272f8a

And I guess using Go, you can use something like the following to validate the JSON against this Json Schema:

https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema

The problem using this might be, if IAM changes their stuff, you have to keep updating the schema on your side.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides an endpoint to validate IAM policies for syntax and best practices. Can be invoked via CLI or API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-policy-validation.html